# Using an external HD to write to and store a mysql Database

Tags: java, sql, mysql

I have set up mysql database to run with java and eclipse on my Mac, it is running great, but now I will generate aprox 4.3billion rows of data which will take up approx 64gbs of data, I'm storing a large about of keys and encrypted values, I have a 1TB external i would like to use as a storage location, i first thought i could reinstall mysql onto the external but it no luck as it obviously isnt running mac osx, Is there anyway i Can point mysql to store a database on the external, i have done some searching but have not come across an answer yet.

I am running Java to build and query the databse and Table if this comes into play.

Thanks.

Comment: Speed is going to suck, unless you're running over USB 3.0 or ESATA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find your mysql config file (typically called `my.cnf`). Change the database path.

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_intro.html#SECTION0001500000

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinstall mysql. You should use both the hdd and the external hard to store the data (rows/tables..) for mysql server.

Maybe by changing the path, but I haven't tried that.