# MySQL cannot write on external hard drive

Tags: mysql

I am trying to store some MySQL tables in my external hard drive as the tables would contain a large amount of data (I would like to keep my default data directory and just store a couple of tables in the external HDD). I added the external hard drive to `innodb_directories`. I tried the below query afterwards:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
  client_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  client_name VARCHAR(75),
  telephone CHAR(15)
)
DATA DIRECTORY = 'alternate directory';
```

It works if I work with a non-external drive directory (adding it to `innodb_directories` and then running this query); however, it returns a generic error when working with external disk.
The mysql error log says:

```
2021-02-20T18:26:05.786051Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 1 means 'Operation not permitted'
2021-02-20T18:26:05.786079Z 8 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] File /Volumes/nasifhdd/mysql_data/openmrsvd: 'mkdir' returned OS error 101
```

I have given all access to this external drive 'drwxrwxrwx'. Still seems mysqld process can't access this directory. How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL tables on external hard drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150707/mysql-tables-on-external-hard-drive)  or [Using an external HD to write to and store a mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307329/using-an-external-hd-to-write-to-and-store-a-mysql-database)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13796865/1445015 This seems relevant. But I don't understand or can locate apparmor

Comment: No, I'm using Mac

Comment: Try to find out why you are getting this error 'File /Volumes/nasifhdd/mysql_data/openmrsvd: 'mkdir' returned OS error 101'

Comment: I'm having this problem since around the time you asked this question as well. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @SammyLarbi, No, I gave up on this. I don't remember the details, but I think I came to a conclusion that it was just not possible. But again, I don't remember much except that I gave up on this.